# Joomla периодически выкидывает на страницу залогивания

Tags: joomla

Только установила joomla на локальный сервер (опенсервер), понемногу разбираюсь в админке. Заметила, что то и дело выкидывает на страницу залогивания. Это можно в каких-то настройках отключить, чтобы этого не происходило?

И еще один вопрос заодно. Установила Joomla 2.5 Russian Language Package, но при входе в админку каждый раз приходится в списке языков выбирать русский. Можно ли как-то настроить, чтобы русский язык там стоял по дефолту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сайт - Общие настройки - Система - Время жизни сессии. 
   Можете поставить срок больше, если поставите 0 то вообще перестанет выкидывать.
2. Расширения - Менеджер языков.
   Тыкните на звездочку рядом с русским языком. Надо что бы она зажглась желтым, если уже желтая то ничего делать не надо. 
   После этого, когда будете заходить в админку язык будет ставится "по умолчанию" (уже русский) и не надо будет переключать.

Comment: всё сделала, большое спасибо за ответы!